# change text input field unity 4.6

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been trying for days without success. How do I change the text of a Unity 4.6 InputField using C# script? I want to do a for loop to change different input when I click in a button.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Function `GetComponentsInChildren` - Returns all **components** of Type type in the GameObject or any of its children.

That means this function returns an Array of Components of Type. But in your code the object with name "texte" is single (is not an Array).

---

Just change your code:

`texte = champ.GetComponentsInChildren<Text> ();`

to

`texte = champ.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ();`

---

Function `GetComponentInChildren` - Returns the **component** of Type type in the GameObject or any of its children using depth first search.

Comment: More explanation would be nice.

Comment: Sure, one moment please